# Can't drive headless using selenium python on Chome version 81 above

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to download a csv from url that have pop up box using selenium python. When I use Chrome version 80.xx and chromedriver 83 it works well while in headless mode. Here it is my script

```
def chrome(path):
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    prefs = {
    "download.default_directory": r"{}".format(path),
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True
    }

    options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
    options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path = r'path\chromedriver.exe')
    #driver.set_window_position(-10000,0)
    return driver

path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'downloaded_files')
driver = chrome(path)

#get into link
driver.get(url)

#insert login
driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.login-button').click()
time.sleep(2)
```

After my Chrome update and version changed to 83. I cant use selenium headless mode again, it says that

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="username"]"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=83.0.4103.116)
```

I've already tried using chrome 81 and chromedriver 83, it gives same problem. Anyone have problem like this?

Comment: It appears that the element is not on the page anymore. It could be that there is a recaptcha or some popup blocking it. Can you save the html to a separate file and inspect it?

Comment: While I inspecting it, it didn't gives me any link. I think it's only a button to post to API and generate a downloadable link

Comment: Can you show us what you receive? It is not necessary that the problem lies in the drivers